# What principles of CAP theorem does Elasticsearch follow?

Tags: elasticsearch, cap-theorem

I have a question on Elasticsearch. With respect to CAP theorem what does Elasticsearch follow out of the three? Some say its CA while some say its AP. Does it depend? I was also reading up on this article - https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/11/please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.html.